# Highcharts Columns with empty columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show a column chart that will show empty columns on days without data.  I have previously done this in amCharts, but trying to switch everything over to js charting.

Here is an example:
https://skitch.com/jhanifen/gy324/jhanifen-skitch.com

Basically if I could change the color of individual columns that would also work.

Comment: Bonus points if you know how to make it look identical to the amCharts version.

Comment: From jlbriggs on highcharts forum:
You can provide either a null or a 0 value for days without data, depending on which is more appropriate for your particular use.
You can change the color of any bar by specifying the fillColor in the data array ie:

    data:[{y:150, fillColor:'#c00'},null,null, 135,35,50,null,null,0,40]

this does not completely solve my problem.

Comment: This helps but how would I have a column have the value of say 100 but on mouseover give the user the value of 0. Because it really is 0 for that day, I just want an empty bar to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided on Highcharts forum.

http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=12873

You can set the y value to 100, and set a secondary value to the actual value, which you can then grab in the tooltip formatter.
see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/BLxUL/

Depending on which you have more of, you can either set the bar color in the plotOptions, and call the 'blank' color in the data array when needed, or the other way around (as in the example)

Thanks jlbriggs!